How to code special parentheses in LaTex?
i have had a little problem the last couple of days. I have no idea how i can code these special parentheses like you can see in the picture. Does anyone know how?

depends on the font but prossibly \left\lgroup\frac{...}{}\right\rgroup

I might add an answer tomorrow. However there is no “specialness” in those delimiters: they’re just stylistic variants of round parentheses and tragically look like mathtype

@egreg yes i wondered about that if it was just a poor font with over-straight parens

That's likely from MathType, which claimed to produce math formulas in Word documents.
However, I find it very hard to reproduce the thing even with mathptmx:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\[
\vec{v}=\vec{s}\,'\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)
\]

\end{document}


Apparently, TeX is unable to reproduce that ugly output. There is nothing special in those parentheses, it's just that MathType was notoriously bad at them.
